# How to change using namespaces in multi-project vstemplate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

I'm creating a custom vstemplate. Every thing is ok and all projects are created successfully with new name. But using namespaces didn't chane to new name .For example , my new project name is SampleWebApi but using namespace is still default namespace.
Here is my main .vstemplate

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="ProjectGroup">
    <TemplateData>
        <Name>Crm365 Web Api</Name>
        <Description>Api Template for dynamic crm 365</Description>
        <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
        <ProjectSubType>
        </ProjectSubType>
        <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
        <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
        <DefaultName>Crm Web Api</DefaultName>
        <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
        <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
        <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
        <CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>
        <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
    </TemplateData>
    <TemplateContent>
        <ProjectCollection>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$.Common" CopyParameters="true">
                ProjectWebApi.Common\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$.Application" CopyParameters="true">
                Project.Application\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$.Domain" CopyParameters="true">
                Project.Domain\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$.Infrastructure" CopyParameters="true">
                Project.Infrastructure\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$.Persistance" CopyParameters="true">
                Project.Persistance\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$" CopyParameters="true">
                ProjectWebApi\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
        </ProjectCollection>
    </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Any Help ?

I spent a lot of time reading Microsoft documentation about how to create custom vstemplate and i tried several ways. but I couldn't find my answer

Comment: Did you look at this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-substitute-parameters-in-a-template?view=vs-2022&source=recommendations

It shows you how to create a parameter value in the code files and then you can add ReplaceParameters="true" in the XML.

Comment: To deal with namespace issues, you need to make sure you update the namespace in each project template.

In each project template (MyTemplate.vstemplate file), you should specify the correct namespace using the $safeprojectname$ parameter.